# NameError: name 'start_new_thead' is not defined

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *
from _thread import start_new_thread

server = "192.168.2.42"
port = 15418

print(f"{server}, {port}")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server,port))
except socket.error as e:
    str(e)

s.listen(2)
print("Server started!")

def threadedClient(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode("Connected"))
    reply = ""
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            reply = data.decode("utf-8")

            if not data:
                print("HEE DISCONNECTETTT")
                break
            else:
                print(f"Received: {reply}")
                print(f"Sending: {reply}")
            conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
        except:
            break

while True:
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    print(f"{addr} joined!")

    start_new_thead(threadedClient,(conn,))
```

hello, im following a tutorial on youtube about sockets. but after a few minutes, i got this error "NameError: name 'start_new_thead' is not defined". i tried "from _thread import start_new_thread" but still the same error. i tried with using the console commandline and did "from _thread import * start_new_thread" but in the console it does not give me an error about that the function is not defined.

Comment: `start_new_thead` is different from `start_new_thread`

Comment: wait im litterly blind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you haven't made any typos, no extra underscores, no capital letters, or mabey there should be capital letters.